# How to directly measure or read the screen capacitance

Tags: hardware, touchscreen

I am looking for a way to directly measure or read the (total or individual grid) change in capacitance as observed by the touchscreen of an android device. Is it possible to achieve this with the default android SDK, or does this require a more extensive knowledge of the hardware?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "capacity"? The amount of pressure one gives to the Touchscreen when he's using the app?

Comment: No, the actual change in capacity of the capacitor that is induced by applying your finger to the screen. If i'm not mistaken, this is measured by the hardware to determine the location of the touch.

Comment: This is not possible. Not even through the SDK. (Okay. It might be possible if you have access to the drivers for the screen and run a self compiled version of the kernel.)

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer! I will look for possible open-source drivers to, at least, try to make it work.

Comment: @TheHippo Can you post your comment as a separate answer? Afterwards, maybe Iska can accept it as an answer. :)

Comment: Keeping this question open. It seems valid, if only to know if the capacitance can be determined in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**. It is not possible to get this information with the Android SDK.

You might get this information if you have access to the drivers and the kernel of your device.